# Overlapping UICollectionView in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

For about 2 weeks I'm trying to find a solution and no luck so far.
Here is my problem:

I have a UIControllerView and I want to put 2 `UICollectionView` (overlapping collections) one over another.

The problem is that I want to work on my collections in my storyboard. I tried and I can't have them one over another (one keeps moving to the cell of the other one).

I tried to use a ContainerView but I can have only one child per container. Si I added another ContainerView over the first one, but in this case I cannot "touch" a cell of the collection view underneath.

UPDATE: Basically I would like to do something like the Facebook Paper App . One UICollectionView half of the height of the one underneath.

Any idea ?

Thanks.

C.C.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? there might be better way - If you have one `UICollectionView` over the other, bottom one won't respond to user gestures..

Comment: In storyboard, the views at the bottom of the view tree are in front of those higher up. If you want to adjust overlapping views, you have to move the view tree to be edited down, adjust it then move it back.

Comment: Yes, but if you try to work like that is horrible. If you want to add labels, modify something it's very difficult having them one over another.

Comment: Is there a way to completely hide a component in storyboard  ? That way I could hide one collection, work on the other one, and at the end make it visible again.

Comment: What you can do is to select the view that is in the way and deselect the "installed' button on the attribute inspector. This removes the view from being in the Size Class you are editing under. Select to add it back.

Comment: I cannot see the Installed button. Where exactly  is it ?

Comment: @CC. Sorry did not get a notify of your comment. The Installed check button is at the very bottom of the attribute inspector. Very last item on the inspector for a view.